# How to obtain certain data from main on a graph using parameter variation in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am having trouble with the coding process or steps to extract data from the main and onto the parameter variation experiment in anylogic. I am currently working on total evacuation time due to random fire obstruction.

For now I have successfully obtained the total max evacuation time for 100 runs in my study but I also need another set of data for the number of exits obstructed during each run. My main has the collection (of 3 exits) availableExits and I can see what is obstructed during the simulation.

Furthermore, I would like to obtain data for the number of people evacuating at a particular time (for example number of pedestrians using exit at 120 seconds). I can see this in main from timeMeasureEnd and creating a histogram distribution graph, which shows number of pedestrians escaping at each time. I've managed to create one in parameter variation but when I run the experiment, I am unable to store or view the data as it keeps changing after every run.

Here is the code from analysis Histogram Data which is entered in after simulation run

`data = root.timeMeasureEnd.distribution;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would recommend to add a dataset to your main which would store all the values you want to keep in parameter variation. Dataset differs from histogram data in a way that it doesnt aggregate, it is just a raw array of values, and later you will not have a problem of "aggregating aggregated data".

So, after each simulation run you can access your dataset in main via "root" reference (as you are already doing it) and loop through it to store all the values one by one.

Comment: I've added a dataset in main. In parameter variation to read data from main i used a variable called iteration1 and dataset1 
Here is the code in after simulation run: 
iteration1++;
dataset1.add(iteration1,root.availableExits());

I get error Description: "The method availableExits() is undefined for the type Main. Location: BlockEFireEvacuation/MonteCarloParametersVariation"

Comment: availableExits - is a collection, right? and you want to save the size of it after every iteration? then just use this code: dataset1.add(iteration1,root.availableExits.size());

Comment: Oh yes it works perfectly. What about the second part. From timeMeasureEnd i want to obtain the amount of data for the amount of people exiting at 120 seconds?

Comment: I just figured that there is no need for variable iteration. I can get the values i need for my study. I still cannot figure out a way to get the information on number of pedestrians exiting, similar to the timeMeasureEnd distribution graph in main 
I tried using dataset2.add(root.timeMeasuredEnd.dataset.distribution());
but it says  "timeMeasuredEnd cannot be resolved or is not a field."

Comment: @Sharrif, maybe a simple typo? You defined "timeMeasureEnd" but in your code line you write "timeMeasuredEnd" ?

Comment: Oh my mistake. I've tried two different codes with errors showing:
1.
dataset2.add(root.timeMeasureEnd.dataset.distribution());
The method distribution() is undefined for the type DataSet. 
2.
dataset2.add(root.timeMeasureEnd.distribution.size());
The method size() is undefined for the type HistogramSmartData.

Comment: I am trying a different approach to solving my problem, because it is getting complicated to read data from timeMeasureEnd distribution.